# memory manager that manages a pre allocated block

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to find a memory management library for C++ that would allocate from an pre-allocated memory block i give it in order to initialise it. After i'm done i will close the allocator (and objects) and free the preallocated block

does something like this already exists?

Comment: it seems it only works with objects of the same size

Comment: maybe a little bit off topic, I guess it would be easy for any allocator to support this, just provide a callback for user to provide there memory block when memory is out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many such allocators. [dlmalloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) is one of the most popular (and it's worked well for us). Doug Lea has [malloc.c](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.c) and [malloc.h](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/malloc.h) available for download, and there are also several derivatives of his original code that are packaged up in possibly more convenient ways, such as [ptmalloc](http://www.malloc.de/en/index.html).

Comment: thanks, the ptmalloc README says that their nothreads version is out of order, which is a pity since i'm hoping of using a custom memory manager that assumes a single thread (no locking overhead)

Comment: @lurscher The base dlmalloc (Doug Lea's malloc.c) may be what you want, then; its thread locking code is more easily removed.

Answer (score 1):

you may be interested in loki's allocators:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/loki-lib/